# PHP ajax search results in mucking up my page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Hi guys its my first time trying out a live ajax search for my site. I am new to php so any help on this matter would be great. I was following some tutorials here and there and trying to make it work, but every time i press search no results come up at all. Any help on this matter would be great.

Code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could not connect");
mysql_select_db("reg") or die ("could not find db");
if (isset($_POST['search_term']) == true && empty($_POST['search_term']) == false) {
    $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_term']);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `ingName` FROM `ing` WHERE `ingName` LIKE '$search_term%'");
    while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false) {
    echo '<li>',$row['ingName'],'</li>';
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" class="searchFunction"> <input type = "submit" value ="Search">
        <div class = "dropdown">
        <ul class = "result">
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.searchFunction').keyup(function() {
        var search_term = $(this) .attr('value');
        $.post('build.php', {search_term:search_term}, function(data) {
            $('.result').html(data);

            $('.result li').click(function() {
            var result_value = $(this).text();
            $('.searchFunction').attr('value', result_value);
            $('.result').html('');
    });
    });
});
});

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Again i am so new to this, so i am just trying to build my knowledge around this area. Any help in solving this big problem out would be great

P.S i know about the sql injections :) but one step at a time for now x

Comment: your input doesn't hold either an id or a `search_term` name attribute. check for errors via PHP http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and check your console.

Comment: the form input element should have a name

Comment: Where is your php code? Can you edit that in your question. Also, why are you using two jquery libs?

Comment: try to `console.log(data)`.. what do you get? You can also use the browsers developer tools (chrome F12) to analyse the XHR traffic which ay show you any errors that might have occurred.

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out - the method used so far is at risk of sql injection so before getting committed to using the now deprecated `mysql` suite of functions you would be wise to read up on and implement `mysqli` which, when you employ `prepared statements` will offer significant protection from malevolent sql injection attacks.

As your ajax query is being sent to the same page ( by the looks of code posted ) one important thing to do is exit from the phpafter sending the response  - otherwise you end up sending the **entire page** ( which would also be badly formed as there would be content outside the html tags ) and I suspect this is not your desired goal.

The ajax function looks, to my untrained eye, ok but as I don't use jQuery I might well be wrong and have missed something important.

```
<?php
    /*
       as the rest of the page doesn't use a db connection, 
       only load the db conn if the page is requested via post
    */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        /* assign db connection to a variable */
        $conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could not connect");

        mysql_select_db("reg") or die ("could not find db");

        /* empty() does an implied `isset` */
        if ( !empty( $_POST['search_term'] ) ) {

            $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['search_term'] );

            /* 
               You ought to look at using mysqli ( prepared statements )
               rather than the now deprecated `mysql_*` functions
            */
            $query = mysql_query( "SELECT `ingName` FROM `ing` WHERE `ingName` LIKE '$search_term%'", $conn );

            if( $query ){/* only send response if the query succeeds */
                while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query ) ) {
                    echo '<li>',$row['ingName'],'</li>';
                }
            }
        }

        mysql_close( $conn );
        /* make sure that the rest of the page is not sent back with the response data */
        exit();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Gotta have a title!</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready( function() {
            $('.searchFunction').keyup( function( event ) {
                /* I could not get this to work - I don't know what this is doing as I don't use jQuery */
                /*var search_term = $(this).attr('value');*/


                /* this however does work */
                var el=event.target || event.srcElement;
                var search_term=el.value;

                /* maybe better to search after a few letters have been added? */
                if( search_term.length < 2 )return;

                /* it appears you are posting to the same page */
                $.post( document.location.href, { search_term:search_term }, function( data ) {
                    $('.result').html( data );

                    $('.result li').click( function( event ) {
                        var result_value = $(this).text();

                        $('.searchFunction').attr('value', result_value );
                        $('.result').html('');
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" name='search_term' class="searchFunction">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <ul class="result"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Full, working example

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        if ( !empty( $_POST['search_term'] ) ) { 

            $dbhost =   'localhost';
            $dbuser =   'root'; 
            $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
            $dbname =   'xxx';

            $db =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

            /* using lower() helped account for vagueries in spelling */
            $sql='select * from `maps` where 
                    lower( `location_name` ) like lower( "%'.$_POST['search_term'].'%" );';

            $res=$db->query( $sql );
            if( $res ){
                while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ){
                    echo "<li>".$rs->location_name."</li>";
                }
            }
        }
        exit();
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <title>Gotta have a title!</title>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $( document ).ready( function() {
            $('.searchFunction').keyup( function( event ) {

                var search_term=this.value;

                /* maybe better to search after a few letters have been added? */
               if( search_term.length < 5 )return;

                /* it appears you are posting to the same page */
                $.post( document.location.href, { search_term:search_term }, function( data ) {
                    $('.result').html( data );

                    $('.result li').click( function( event ) {
                        var result_value = $(this).text();

                        $('.searchFunction').attr( 'value', result_value );
                        $('.result').html('');
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='container'>
        <input type='text' name='search_term' class='searchFunction'>
        <input type='submit' value='Search'>
        <div class='dropdown'>
            <ul class='result'></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: C'mon Ram - you know that code only answers are ***bad*** answers. :)

Comment: i did put in comments here and there - but truth be told - my heart really isn't in it at the moment

Comment: Sorry to hear that Ram.

Comment: thought i'd better add some notes - you are right of course, code only answers are bad

Comment: Hi there thanks so much for the answer, back , however for some reason it still is not working now

Comment: No drop down function appears now when i write in the box

Comment: Is it because i have the javascript at the bottom of the page? althought i dont think that would make a difference

Comment: Ah when i use the google chrome to see the developer tool it says  that this line is an error "  if( search_term.length < 2 )return;" uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: aha - ok, just delete that line ~ I only put it in so that you don't do a search on a single character. But the fact that it says of undefined suggests that `search_term` is blank. Try adding in an alert statement or similar ~ ie `alert( search_term )` before the ajax request

Comment: Hmm i tried this, and it fixed that problem however now it shows nothing, for example i write some words but nothing appears

Comment: Is the ajax request sent ok ( look in the console ) and how far into the php do you get if the ajax is sent ok ( put debug statements in )? I just ran this up using mysqli and a search of one of my tables and it was fine so it suggests that the problem might well be in the php. I found that the `like` operator was case-sensitive ( curiously ) in the results ~ is that a possibility for your lack of results here?

Comment: @RamRaider I am not to sure , i have mae sure all is correct but still not working, i will keep going and see what i can do

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing your query without the quotations ie:

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT ingName FROM ing WHERE ingName   LIKE   '$search_term%'");
```

and you can also loosen your search by using `'%$search_term%'` instead of `'$search_term'`.

Another possible issue is the `mysql_connect()`. I was using that function and it did not work for me so I resolved to the `mysqli_connect()` function which worked for me.

Some more advise, you do not need the `==true` and you can also you can use 
`!empty($_POST['search_term'])`.

Once you are through learning that you can also try the PDO function which is far much better than initiating your own connection.
You initiate a PDO connection like this.

`$dbh1 = new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbname;host=127.0.0.1', 'username', 'dbpass');`

Then you can search like this. - using the initialized connection.

```
 $query = "SELECT ingName from ing WHERE ingName LIKE %$search_term%";
 $stmt = $dbh1->prepare($query);
 $stmt->execute();
 $allRows = count($stmt);
 $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::fetch_assoc);
 foreach($row as $one){
      echo "<li>".$one['ingName']."</li><br>";
 }
```

Cheers!

Comment: Those are called back ticks and you *should* use them as it is just good form in a query.